# Riot.js How to repeat tag a certain number of times?

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I need just repeat tag 5 times. I read documentation, but did not realize how to do something like this:

```
<some-tag>
   <star repeat={5} />
</some-tag>
```

I found only this ugly way:

```
<some-tag>
   <star each={stars} />

   this.stars = new Array(5);
</some-tag>
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking through the source, [this](https://github.com/riot/riot/blob/f66a47ffcf9807280dbaaf32da2f3aa8a0a12134/lib/browser/tag/each.js#L148) might interest you.

If you plan on using the `each` attribute, you'll have to define some sort of an array for riot to pass to `forEach`.

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6k6osto/) is another idea (that isn't optimal), but I think it illustrates the point. Another solution is to use Riot's `mixin` system to build some sort of `repeat` attribute:

https://jsfiddle.net/aunn3gt0/2/

It's a great solution until you try using the `<yield/>` tag. Then it may need to be adjusted. Here's how it works:

```
var repeat = {
  init: function() {
    var repeats = [],
        count = this.opts.repeat

    this.on('mount', function() {
      if (!count) return

      var impl = this.root.innerHTML
      this.root.removeAttribute('repeat')

      while(repeats.length < count) {
        var clone = this.root.cloneNode()
        this.root.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, this.root)
        clone.innerHTML = impl
        repeats.push(riot.mount(clone))
      }
    })

    this.on('unmount',function(){
      repeats.forEach(function(tag,i){
        tag.unmount()
      })
    })

  }
}
```

Then just attach it with `this.mixin(repeat)` and use it as you would expect:

```
<tag repeat="10">Repeated 10 times.</tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what you've proposed, you can do this right in the template:

```
<some-tag>
   <star each="{(NOTHING, i) in Array(state.repeatCount)}" />
</some-tag>
```

In this example, `i` contains the index.